# Can i get english transliteration of translated text from Google cloud translation API

Tags: cloud, translation, google-translation-api

When i visit translate.google.com I can see that they provide english transliteration of translated text. Eg I am translating something from English to Hindi I am trying to fetch english Transliterated text for the response translation. I have not been able to figure out if Google cloud translation API supports this or not.

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking at the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) link, I was unable to find that it supports such feature (transliteration of translated text). Thus, I would suggest you file an [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to request it.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is currently in preview under the Cloud Translation API (Translate Text Advanced v3) offering.

> Transliteration is a configuration setting in the **translateText** method. When you enable transliteration, you translate romanized text (Latin script) directly to a target language.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3#transliteration

No news on when it will go GA (generally available).